# A concept in CSAPP: what is the definition of instruction?

Tags: cpu, concept

I am now reading CSAPP, in chapter 4, there are some discussions about cpu pipelining features where the author talks about how many instructions a non-pipelining cpu can execute within 1 second VS a pipelining cpu. I post the screenshot as follows:
[image]

[image]

in this figure 4.32(a) shows an unpipelined cpu. In this implementation, we must complete one instruction before beginning the next. the big box is the combinational logic. The author regard this whole process as an instruction and calculates the throughput as 3.12 GIPS as shown in the formula.

then the author use figure 4.33 to show the pipeline computation:
[image]

In this pipeline computation, the combinational logic can be divided into 3 stages I1, I2 and I3. Now here is my question: In my opinion, because all these 3 stages are combined to product as an effect of the combinational logic, I will think of the 3 stages as a single instruction just as what the author did in the unpipelined example. However, the author seems to regard the 3 stages as 3 instructions, and got the throughput of 8.33 GIPS as follows:

[image]

SO I am curious what is exactly the definition of instruction? (if we think of writing to registers as an instruction, then the author's answer is correct)